How to define the models to use with PaddleOCR?
I want to try different models in PaddleOCR, so I am doing this:
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
ocr = PaddleOCR(det_model_name='en_PP-OCRv3_det', rec_model_name='en_number_mobile_v2.0_rec', lang='en')

However, regardless of what values I use for det_model_name and rec_model_name, nothing seems to change. Even when I use some random strings here, the PaddleOCR constructor does not complain. What am I doing wrong or how can I verify PaddleOCR uses the given models?
